# CAS Authentication failed! while using ohocas client

Tags: php, single-sign-on, phpcas, rubycas-server

I've setup the rubycas-server with mysql backend. But when i tried to login via a phpCAS client, it is redirected to rubycas-server url. but, after entering username & password - I got this error

CAS Authentication failed!

You were not authenticated.

You may submit your request again by clicking here.

If the problem persists, you may contact the administrator of this site.

CAn u tell me...whats wrong with my phpcas client..Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem which generally comes with the development servers when we use no `SSL::setNoCasServerValidation();`
However even after using `setNoCasServerValidation()`, the CAS Client internally calls the `curl` using https, which is the main cause of this error.

So to fix it just go to CAS Library file `../CAS/CAS/Client.php`
Reach the function

```
private function _readURL($url, &$headers, &$body, &$err_msg){}
```

and add this line

```
$url = str_replace("https", "http", $url);
```

as the first line of function `_readURL(...`

Please don't do this in production environment as CAS recommends use of SSL on production.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the certificate on the CAS server solved the problem for me.